# How do I find the 2nd most recent order of a customer

Tags: mysql, sql, max

I have the customers first order date and last order date by doing MIN and MAX on the created_at field (grouping by email), but I also need to get the customers 2nd most recent order date (the order date right before the last orderdate )

```
SELECT 
    customer_email, 
    COUNT(entity_id) AS NumberOfOrders, 
    MIN(CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'UTC','US/Mountain')) AS 'FirstOrder', 
    MAX(CONVERT_TZ(created_at,'UTC','US/Mountain')) AS 'MostRecentOrder',
    SUM(grand_total) AS TotalRevenue, 
    SUM(discount_amount) AS TotalDiscount
FROM sales_flat_order 
WHERE 
    customer_email IS NOT NULL
    AND store_id = 1
GROUP BY customer_email
LIMIT 500000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` (available in MySQL 8.0):

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_email ORDER BY created_at) rn_asc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_email ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn_desc
    FROM sales_flat_order
    WHERE customer_email IS NOT NULL AND store_id = 1
) x
WHERE rn_asc = 1 OR rn_desc <= 2
```

This will get you the earlierst and the two latest orders placed by each customer.

Note: it is unclear what the timezone conversions are intended for. I left them apart, since they obviously do not affect the sorting order; feel free to add them as per your use case.

---

If you want a single record per customer, along with its total count of orders, and the date of his first, last, and last but one order, then you can aggregate in the outer query:

```
SELECT 
    customer_email,
    NumberOfOrders,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_asc = 1 THEN created_at END) FirstOrder,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_desc = 1 THEN created_at END) MostRecentOrder,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn_desc = 2 THEN created_at END) MostRecentButOneOrder,
    TotalRevenue,
    TotalDiscount
FROM (
    SELECT 
        customer_email,
        created_at,
        COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_email) NumberOfOrders,
        SUM(grand_total) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_email) TotalRevenue, 
        SUM(discount_amount) OVER(PARTITION BY customer_email) TotalDiscount,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_email ORDER BY created_at) rn_asc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY customer_email ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn_desc
    FROM sales_flat_order
    WHERE customer_email IS NOT NULL AND store_id = 1
) x
GROUP BY customer_email
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! That is awesome. I am still digging into it and trying to figure it out! I didn't know about ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY, so I am very grateful for you, and I will keep reading and researching.
For the inside query, I am getting an error that I am trying to figure out right now
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY customer_email) NumberOfOrders,
        SUM(grand_total) OVER(PAR' at line 4

Comment: @ChristopherV: which version of MySQL are you using? You can run `SELECT @@vrsion` to find out.

Comment: 5.6.33-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log  --- ah sad day, works for 8.0 - hmm

Comment: @ChristopherV: unfortunately window functions (such as `ROW_NUMBER()`) were added in MySQL 8.0, as indicated in my answer. Can you consider upgrading your database? 5.6 is an old version.

Comment: Yeah - I will definitely have to do that. But know of any workarounds to get the 2nd most recent order on 5.6?